# Decrypt CryptoJS in PHP - where does the IV go

Tags: php, encryption

I am using this function to supply a custom key for encrypting a string using CryptoJS

```
function doHash(msg){
    msg = String(msg);
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, { iv: iv });
    return encrypted;

}
```

*Instead of supplying a passphrase I directly supply an IV and a key to encrypt.*

Now I need to decrypt the ciphertext in PHP:
And this is what I found:

```
function aes_decrypt($encrypted,$key)
{
    // if $encrypted is HEXed, then return it to binary
    $encrypted = pack('H*',$encrypted);

    $key = mysql_aes_key($key);
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$encrypted,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,''),"\x00..\x1F");
}
```

This is a direct example of mCrypt's decrypt AES function.

> I cannot see anywhere where the IV goes to decrypt this. Am I missing
>   something, is the IV not needed when decrypting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty clear [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php):

```
string mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , 
                        string $mode [, string $iv ] )
```

So the last argument is where the IV should go. In your current code, you are passing an empty string (`''`).